# Is there any way to get more information about this error?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the following post to try and get the results of a query printed out to a file: [Save a SQL query result to an XML file without SSIS or xp_cmdshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788951/save-a-sql-query-result-to-an-xml-file-without-ssis-or-xp-cmdshell)

But when I run it I get an error saying:

```
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure WriteToFile, Line 42
Error whilst Creating file "C:\TEMP\SQL_XML\test.xml",
```

I was wondering if there is any way to get more information about why exactly it errrored? I dont know much about debugging SQL queries. Im using SQL Server 2008 with SQL Server Management Studio. unfortunately

Comment: Does it really say "whilst" in the error message?   That's awesome.   : )

Comment: Yes it does, but that comes from the error handling code through the link

Comment: Oh, do you mean that this error message is generated by some error-handling code that you own?   If so, can you bypass it to get the actual error message returned by SQL Server?

Comment: Its using sp_OAMethod so I get a hr result = -2146828212. I found on here: https://www.simple-talk.com/community/forums/thread/71841.aspx someone had the same error and it didnt like their path. I tried the same thing they did but it didnt work. I get a hr result = -2146828218. How do I find out what the error code means in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

If you convert HRESULT  -2146828218  to HEX you get `800A0046` and if you google for 0x800A0046 you'll find

> CTL_E_PERMISSIONDENIED

Most plausible is that the identity running the COM Scripting.FileSystem object doesn't have permissions to write in `C:\TEMP\SQL_XML`. So verify that the Sql Service user has permission to create files in C:\TEMP\SQL_XML.

A second option might be that the file already exists.

A third option might be that the file is already in use.